# Hiding a div conditionally with jQuery

Tags: jquery, show-hide

How can I hide div 1 and show div 2 if condition is true in jQuery?

Here is my code:

```
<div class="div1">Content 1 </div>
<div class="div2">Content 2 </div>

function(someFunction) {
    var option = this.config.option;
    if (someFunction && this.config.option == true) {
        option = this.config.option;
    }
    $$('div.div1').each(function(el) {
        $(el).hide(); //and add show div2 ?
    });
};
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using `each()` with `div.div1`? There's only 1 such element.

Comment: @BackinaFlash - ...and even if there were more, `.hide()` will take care of all of them.

Comment: Hi @Back in a Flash, im using each() because i need to get each value from this.config.option and some can be false. Thanks

Comment: Did 3 people really upvote this? I've re-read this question 6 times, and I still don't know what he's trying to accomplish here...

Comment: And precisely what condition does the visibility of the `div` depend on? Can you explain what it is that you're testing, what the options might be?

Comment: Sorry for my bad english, what i want is to hide one div and show other if the condition is true. Thanks

Comment: I got that. But what condition? What is the test you're performing?

Comment: false, if is true hide div1 and show div2, doesn't matter for what condition im asking, the if the function found some value will return true if not will return false, and in that case will do nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="div1">Content 1 </div>
<div class="div2">Content 2 </div>

function(someFunction) {
    var option = this.config.option;
    if (someFunction && this.config.option) {
        option = this.config.option;
    }
if(option === 'Yes'){
    $$('div.div1').each(function(el) {
        $(el).hide();
    })
    $$('div.div2').each(function(el) {
        $(el).show();
    })
    }

if(option === 'No'){
    $$('div.div1').each(function(el) {
        $(el).show();
    })
    $$('div.div2').each(function(el) {
        $(el).hide();
    })
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using the [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function?

```
$('div.div1').toggle(option);
$('div.div2').toggle(!option);
```

Answer (score 0):

As the commenters mentioned, there's no need to use  each().
This should do it:

```
<div class="div1">Content 1 </div>
<div class="div2">Content 2 </div>

function hide1show2() {
    $('div.div1').hide(); 
    $('div.div2').show();
}
```

Comment: Which has zero relevance to the question, given the `show()`/`hide()` depends on the assessment of a condition.

Comment: Presumably, the OP knows what an 'if' statement is?

Comment: Presumably, he also clearly (from the question) knows how to use `hide()`. So without more information all people can do, and seem to be doing, is leaving guesses. I'm not down-voting, but this answer doesn't seem useful.